# Drupal7: How to preserve intent, white space, new link break in full html mode tinymce?

Tags: drupal, tinymce

- How to preserve intent, white space, new link break in full html mode with Tinymce?
- The nice formatted html code will be trimmed (become 1 single line), after people switch between filtered html mode & full html mode.

Comment: Hack: set $setting["apply_source_formatting"] = true in tinymce.inc

Answer (score 2):

@kenpeter suggestion worked for me, though you don't need to tamper with the wysiwyg module just implement the following hook in a module of your own:

```
function MODULE_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter ( &$settings, $context ) {

    if ( $context[ 'profile' ]->editor !== 'tinymce' ) {
        return;
    }

    // Fix formatting on html source view
    $settings[ 'apply_source_formatting' ] = true;
}
```

Comment: Setting $settings["apply_source_formatting"] = true doesn't work for me, even after clearing all caches.